# Filezilla - can't access folder when connecting with other computer using ip adress but works localhost

Tags: ftp, filezilla

When I am connecting using localhost on the computer the filezilla server lies on it works perfectly fine, but when I connect with IP-Adress (It is port-forwarded correctly, im 100% sure of that) this happens:

```
Status: Connecting to **.**.**.**:800...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (**,**,**,**,***,***)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - 
Connection refused by server
Response:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: Firewall? NAT? What ports are open on your firewall?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @EssemCSH did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, it's usually a firewall configuration problem.

Besides a control connection, FTP also uses a data connection on a different port that needs to be assigned before data trasfers.

This means that you must open ports on your firewall to allow data transfers and, of course, you should make FileZilla Server aware of that.

For passive mode transfers, you should set a *range* of ports from the window below:

[image]

Of course those ports should be open at the firewall too. A longer discussion can be find [here](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=24925).